# Thread-safe adding records to chrome.storage.local

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**What I would like to do.**

I would like my extension to store some information about browser usage in `chrome.storage.local` and if collected data is big enough, to send it via ajax to my database and of course clear it so the same data wouldn't get send again.

**What is the problem.**

The problem is, that `chrome.storage.local.get` is async function operating on callbacks:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('data',function(data){...})
```

... and there is no built in method to append some object that is stored. So it seems, that the only way to add new `data`, when there will be something to add, would be to do something like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('data',function(data){
   data.push('some new information');
   chrome.storage.local.set({'data' : data},function(){}
})
```

But this isn't safe. For example when alot of data from multiple sources would come, there would be great posibility, that some information would get lost, as few events could read `data` at same time, without even knowing that some other event is appending this data at same time, so basically, only the last (I mean execution time) event would write it correctly, and all others would get overwritten, as other records were not in storage yet, when event was triggered.

The same thing with sending...

```
chrome.storage.local.get('data',function(data){...}){
   chrome.storage.local.set({'data':[]},function(){})
   sendViaAjax(data);
}
```

As clearing is async, it could get cleared during writting proccess of some events that occured between `get` and `set`.

**And the question is...**

How do I make it right, so there wouldn't be possibility (or at least it would get minimalized) that some data would get lost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to prevent race condition in multiple chrome.storage API calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050861/best-way-to-prevent-race-condition-in-multiple-chrome-storage-api-calls)

Comment: Are you talking about multiple sources on one webpage? If yes, JavaScript is single-threaded so there's no such possibility. But if you referring to many instances of the same extension (eg, content scripts) you can move "save" logic to the background page which can be only one. Each extension page calling bg page execute command one after another.

Comment: @PawełPsztyć "here's no such possibility" it is not true. Imagine I do it inside of onBeforeSendHeaders listener... so there are few simultanous ajax requests (imagine they are to different urls).. so they are really simultanous and this kind of data racing is a big problem

Comment: Yes, Paweł is right... it can send multiple times same records without clearing them.

Comment: @FlashThunder An for example, imagine I want in my pluigin to count all images loaded on page using onCompleted event of webRequest. Let's say I do in like that:

    chrome.webRequest.onComplete.addListener(function(data) {
        chrome.storage.local.get('count', function(data) {
            data.count++;
            chrome.storage.local.set(data, function(data) {});
        });
    },{urls: ["*.jpg"]},
    []);

I would definitely produce data racing and as a result data loss.

I'm sorry comments doesn't mantain text formatting

Comment: @FlashThunder it is possible that there is already answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050861/best-way-to-prevent-race-condition-in-multiple-chrome-storage-api-calls