# JavaScript event handler working with an async data store API causing race condition

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, events, promise

I need to update some data every time certain browser event fires (for example, when a browser tab closes):

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(async (tabId) => {
  let data = await getData(); // async operation

  ...                         // modify data 

  await setData(data);        // async operation
});
```

The problem is, when multiple such event triggers in quick succession, the async `getData()` could return stale result in subsequent invocation of the event handler before `setData()` gets a chance to finish in earlier ones, leading to inconsistent result.

If the event handler can execute synchronously then this problem wouldn't occur, but `getData()` and `setData()` both are async operations.

Is this a race condition? What's the recommended pattern to handle this type of logic?

**--- Update ---**

To provide more context, `getData()` and `setData()` are simply promisified version of some Chrome storage API:

```
async function getData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(data) => {
      // callback
    });
  });
}

async function setData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ key: value }, function() => {
      // callback
    });
  });
}
```

I wrapped the API call in a Promise for readability purposes, but I think it's an async op either way?

Comment: Yes, this is a classic race condition. Use semaphors or queues.

Comment: Please show us what `getData` and `setData` do exactly. Maybe there's a solution specific to that API - e.g. transactions in a database.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I made an update above.

Comment: Chrome set and get uses a callback, doesn't need the promise at all.

Comment: You can use a functor, passing the the callback. This solves the problem.
On that function you i'll need closures to trigger the event, so, f(..args)(fn).

Comment: Correcting, you i'll need the promise the block the JS from not triggering the actions, if it's a chrome extensions this is not needed. I'm rambling on this, this is unsure.

Comment: @winniethemu Thanks. Take a look at [Best way to prevent race condition in multiple chrome.storage API calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15050861/1048572) then (although I'm not sure whether there is a *good* solution)

Comment: Plop that callback on a queue, which is not complicated just watch an array then fire the pushed function. In my test its async but processed synchronously.. see snippet: https://playcode.io/634360/  I upvoted but wont answer, your welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fairly classic race condition for a data store with an asynchronous API and the race condition is even worse if you use asynchronous operations in the processing of the data (between the `getData()` and `setData()`.  The asynchronous operations allow another event to run in the middle of your processing, ruining the atomicity of your sequence of events.

Here's an idea for how to put the incoming tabId in a queue and make sure you're only processing one of these events at a time:

```
const queue = [];

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(async (newTabId) => {
    queue.push(newTabId);
    if (queue.length > 1) {
        // already in the middle of processing one of these events
        // just leave the id in the queue, it will get processed later
        return;
    }
    async function run() {
        // we will only ever have one of these "in-flight" at the same time
        try {
            let tabId = queue[0];
            let data = await getData(); // async operation

            ...                         // modify data 

            await setData(data);        // async operation
        } finally {
            queue.shift();              // remove this one from the queue
        }
    }
    while (queue.length) {
        try {
            await run();
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            // decide what to do if you get an error
        }
    }
});
```

---

This could be made more generic so it could be reusably used in more than place (each with their own queue) like this:

```
function enqueue(fn) {
    const queue = [];
    return async function(...args) {
        queue.push(args);       // add to end of queue
        if (queue.length > 1) {
            // already processing an item in the queue,
            // leave this new one for later
            return;
        }
        async function run() {
            try {
                const nextArgs = queue[0];  // get oldest item from the queue
                await fn(...nextArgs);      // process this queued item
            } finally {
                queue.shift();              // remove the one we just processed from the queue
            }
        }
        // process all items in the queue
        while (queue.length) {
            try {
                await run();
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
                // decide what to do if you get an error
            }
        }
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(enqueue(async function(tabId) {
    let data = await getData(); // async operation

    ...                         // modify data

    await setData(data);        // async operation
}));
```

Comment: "*You could probably also use the newer atomics to manage the access.*" - no, that's aimed at shared memory (array buffers). As long as your code is all in the same realm/event loop, a global synchronisation object (like your `queue`) is the way to go.

Comment: @Bergi - OK, I removed that line.

Comment: That's a clean solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

JS ascync/await does not really turns JS code synchronous.

What you cold do is block the event loop on getData using Promisse.all.

So,

```js
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(async (tabId) => {
   ...                         // turns in a composition 

  await setData(Promise.all([getData])[0]); // async composition
});
```

You cold do a async composition with a block on event loop, when the event is triggered, the VM will have a list with events, and a block on the await getData.

In fact does not exist async composition, is just a trick with the VM to block the event loop and awaits to the result of an operation cause the VM process this as a list and lists don't wait.

Be careful with your code to become readable when using compositions.

Comment: "*it's not a race condition*" - no. "*you could block the event loop*" - no.

Comment: Exaplain the minus 1 flag, is not a race condition because. It's not a parallel code, just the internals. If you consider that, async function compostion is a response.

Comment: Race conditions can also occur in normal *concurrent* code. You don't need multithreading or hardware parallelism for that.

Comment: Thanks. but this is processed in a queue, add the event loop an you get the trick.
So, yes, is a race condition. Thanks.

Comment: Completing the response, You are using a queue to do this.

Comment: @Bergi, Promissel.all inside an composition blocks turning the code synchronous, considering the interns of the VM you are "blocking" the event loop. Just a point.

Comment: "*`Promise.all` blocks, turning the code synchronous*" - no. No it doesn't. Although I have no idea what you mean by "*inside an composition*".

Comment: In fact JS code it's not imperative, to be that they i'll need to be synchronous. When you have a race condition like that, you can transform in a composition and uses the interns of the VM to process that.

By inside a composition I'm talking about asynchronous functions in a composition. I skip steps on this.

Comment: Any time you have `await` or `.then()`, there's a chance for other event handlers to run while you're waiting for those promises to resolve.  That allows another one of these events to start and cause a race condition.  This is a classic race condition in Javascript caused by asynchronous operations.  You can't get around it like you are attempting to.  That won't help.  Also, `await` doesn't block the event loop.  It only blocks the current function execution.  The event loop continues to run other events.

Comment: So, Promisse.all does the trick. I'm not sure if i'm being a _headstrong_, but it's a trick i've learned when search compositions. I'm being tempted to do more research on this topic, but the tests concludes that using Promisse.all you can block an assyncronous functions inside a composition. I've research a lot the functional world and compositons. On that case you don't have a .then method, so, it's really do a trick. About the event loop, I talked about it on the _to be imperative_.